# Getting memory leak with my shared pointers?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my base class  I have a vector of pointers of my derived class, e.g.

`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fing*>> files;`

In my derived abstract class I have a factory method that looks like

`static std::shared_ptr<Fing*> create(const std::string filetype, const std::string &path);`

The derived abstract class Fing* has three other classes derived from it which I will call derived A,B,C. So my vector in my base class of shared_ptr is really more like a vector of `shared_ptr<A* or B* or C*>`

So the factory method itself looks like

```
shared_ptr<Fing*> Fing::create(const std::string fileType, const 
string &filepath){

if (fileType == "a"s){
    return make_shared<Fing*>(new A(filepath));
}
if (fileType == "b"s){
    return make_shared<Fing*>(new B(filepath));
}
    return make_shared<Fing*>(new C(filepath)); }
```

I call the factory method as such

`shared_ptr<Fing*> newA(Fing::create("a","path here"));`

and push it to my vector like this

`myfiles.emplace_back(move(newA));`

However, even though my base class is being destructed valgrind says there is a leak coming from my factory method?

Comment: I assume you want a shared pointer to a `Fing` not a shared pointer to a pointer to a `Fing`? If so you need `std::shared_ptr<Fing>` not `std::shared_ptr<Fing*>`!

Comment: Should I be changing my factory method to <Fing> instead? When I do that I get `invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Fing’`

Comment: You probably want `return std::make_shared<A>(filepath);`?

Comment: The reason for using smart pointers is to lift you off the burden of manual memory management. Using operator `new` in conjunction with smart pointers is rarely the case. And it's never the case in combination with the factory functions `make_shared` and `make_unique`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you shouldn't specify that the parameter to a `std::shared_ptr` is a pointer, that is *implicit*.

So your declarations need to be more like this:

```
class Fing
{
public:
    Fing(std::string const&) {}
    virtual ~Fing() {}
};

class A: public Fing { public: A(std::string const& s): Fing(s) {}};
class B: public Fing { public: B(std::string const& s): Fing(s) {}};
class C: public Fing { public: C(std::string const& s): Fing(s) {}};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fing>> files;

std::shared_ptr<Fing> create(const std::string &filepath)
{
    return std::make_shared<A>(filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::shared_ptr` is a smart pointer, it holds a pointer internally for you, and manages its lifetime.  But you are misusing `std::shared_ptr`.  You should never set its `T` template parameter to a pointer type, only to the actual type it should be pointing to.  Pointing to a pointer defeats the purpose of using a smart pointer.

You are also misusing `std::make_shared()`, too.  The whole point of using `std::make_shared()` is to avoid having to use `new` explicitly, and to allocate an initial `std::shared_ptr<T>` more efficiently then using `new` by itself can.  `std::make_shared()` allocates the `T` you specify, forwarding its own arguments to `T`'s constructor.

Dynamically allocating a pointer yourself, and then creating a `std::shared_ptr` that has its own dynamically allocated pointer that is a copy of your pointer, is pretty useless.

Try this instead:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fing>> files;

...

std::shared_ptr<Fing> Fing::create(const std::string &fileType, const std::string &filepath)
{
    if (fileType == "a"s){
        return make_shared<A>(filepath);
    }
    if (fileType == "b"s){
        return make_shared<B>(filepath);
    }
    return make_shared<C>(filepath);
}

...

auto newA = Fing::create("a", "path here");
myfiles.push_back(std::move(newA));

or just:

myfiles.push_back(Fing::create("a","path here"));
```